# NSKeyedUnarchiver Memory Leak

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks

I have this code to load a set of properties from file, then assigning it.

```
NSMutableData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];
NSKeyedUnarchiver* unarc = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
NSMutableArray* loadedLibraries = [unarc decodeObjectForKey:@"libraries"];
IRStudyPlan* loadedStudyPlan = [unarc decodeObjectForKey:@"currentStudyPlan"];
NSMutableDictionary* loadedWordLists = [unarc decodeObjectForKey:@"wordLists"];
NSMutableDictionary* loadedStudyPlanList = [unarc decodeObjectForKey:@"studyPlanList"];
[unarc finishDecoding];
[self setLibraries:loadedLibraries];
[self setStudyPlanList:loadedStudyPlanList];
[self setCurrentStudyPlan:loadedStudyPlan];
[self setWordLists:loadedWordLists];
[unarc release];
```

I wonder why I has memory leak on every object. My initWithCoder is this one, similar for all objects:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder{
if([super init]!=nil){
    [self setListName:[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"listName"]];
    [self setWordsWithStatistics:[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"wordsWithStatistics"]];
    [self setWordsWithStatisticsInGame:[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"wordsWithStatisticsInGame"]];
}
return self;
```

}

Can anyone enlighten me?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

Instruments will show where the leaked memory was allocated, in your case from the NSKeyedUnarchiver.  Most likely, you are leaking the object that contains this code.  Look at the lifecycle of the object that this code comes from.